# Trigger doesn't get created, despite no errors being detected

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, dbeaver

Table:

```
create table produto
(
    referencia varchar(3) primary key,
    descricao varchar(50) unique,
    estoque int not null default 0,
    preco_normal decimal(10,2),
    preco_desconto decimal(10,2)
);
```

Trigger (I tried creating it without a delimiter to no avail as well):

```
delimiter //
create trigger desconto before insert 
on produto
for each row 
begin 
    if new.estoque < 5 then 
        set new.preco_desconto = new.preco_normal * 0.90;
    else
        set new.preco_desconto = new.preco_normal;
    end if;
end//
delimiter ;
```

The trigger result:

[image]

But when I use `drop trigger if exists desconto;`

The output says *Trigger does not exist*

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Refresh the database (right click database choose refresh, then you should see the defined trigger).

Comment: It didn't work either, but I executed the same script in MYSQL Workbench and everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: DBEAVER does not support the `DELIMITER` statement, see: https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=818

Comment: @Luuk 's answer is the good one. Execute the create trigger query from "create..." to "end" and bypass the delimiter statements and it works.
Here's a link about delimiter support in Dbeaver: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/301

Comment: @8oris The link you've sent states that DBeaver supports DELIMITERs since 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a production environment on DBeaver?

If so, it may be required to COMMIT your changes after you run the query, to actually apply your changes. Check the Commit button below, located by the bar at the top, in DBeaver 23.0.0.

[image: Commit button in DBeaver]

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is possible to delete a (just created) trigger before doing the `COMMIT`.  see: https://dbfiddle.uk/KIu3zfWn

Comment: What I meant is to commit the query to create the trigger. The problem the OP have is that the trigger is not being created. It's not about creating and deleting on the same transaction, as your example query does.